# httpUrlConnextion.getContentLength returning incorrect value

Tags: java, android, json, url, httpurlconnection

```
HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection)blogFeedUrl.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
                int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
```

So i have those 2 lines of code,when :

```
URL blogFeedUrl = new URL("http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=2");
```

everything works fine and contentLength get an acceptable value.
but when:

```
URL blogFeedUrl = new URL("http://raja12.esy.es/api/get_recent_summary/?count=2");
```

getContentLength is returning -1 and it doesn't work.
The thing is that the two url are similar(you can check). That's so confusing! 
Thnank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers from each server differs. 
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=2 returns content-length but http://raja12.esy.es/api/get_recent_summary/?count=2 headers do not contains content-length header.

You can see headers if You press F12 in browser, go to Network tab and run request. You will see 2 operations - your get and favicon get. Check your get for headers.

Suppose You can change settings of server or just ignore content-length header if it less then 0

Comment: please let me know if you see an alternative

Comment: If you want to use HttpURLConnection you can get InputStream from it and then use http://stackoverflow.com/a/309448/1003030

Answer (score 0):

From this [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), the content length may be larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE (65535).

Can you try with  `getContentLengthLong()` instead and see the results?

Comment: that's weard, it doesn't recognize the method getContentLengthLong() :(

Comment: however i don't think the length could be this larger